# How to filter entries with null value in date field?

Tags: datetime, craft2

I have date field in entry that is empty therefore has `null` value.
I'd like to filter entries that have `date` field value equal to `null`.

How would I set that parameter on element criteria object? I don't want to achieve it by looping yet because I'm merging entries from another section.

---

Setting it to `null` returns entries with or without value.

```
{% set myEntries = craft.entries.section("mySection").date(null) %}
```

Setting it to `""` returns entries with or without value.

```
{% set myEntries = craft.entries.section("mySection").date("") %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special strings `:empty:` and `:notempty:` might be what you're looking for. The docs list it only against expiryDate, but I think it's available for any field: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#expirydate